# Динамические точки в строчке

Tags: html, css, sass, scss, background

Есть вот такой макет: 
[image: Скриншот]

Вопрос: как сделать точки между заголовком и значением ?
Значения справа могут иметь разную длину символов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>exp</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>1000</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>lorem20</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>ip10</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>do</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>50</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>dollor</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>1000</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>dollorin</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>400</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Наверно, лучше добавить между 2 `span` ещё 1 `span` и уже ему задать границу из точек)

Comment: А сам и не додумался :)
Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: раз уж используется `flex`, вместо установки `display` и `width` можно воспользоваться `flex-grow`

Comment: @Grundy `width` даёт хоть частичную поддержку там где не поддерживается `flex-grow`